# How to convert time in milli seconds to different local times using timezone

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I need to convert time in millisecond to a specific time zone using node.js or JavaScript.

I have a unix time "1497678894647". I need to convert this to PDT, MDT, CDT, EDT, MST, EST & IST local times.

I have following code sample.

```
var timezoneJS = require('timezone-js');

var PDT = new timezoneJS.Date('1497680592200', 'America/New_York');
var MDT = new timezoneJS.Date('1497680592200', 'America/Chihuahua');
var CDT = new timezoneJS.Date('1497680592200', 'America/Havana');
var EDT = new timezoneJS.Date('1497680592200', 'America/Detroit');
var MST = new timezoneJS.Date('1497680592200', 'America/Creston');
var IST = new timezoneJS.Date('1497680592200', 'Asia/Kolkata');



console.log("PDT  --> ", dt);
console.log("MDT  --> ", dt);
console.log("CDT  --> ", dt);
console.log("EDT  --> ", dt);
console.log("MST  --> ", dt);
console.log("EST  --> ", dt);
console.log("IST  --> ", dt);
```

But I got output like this

```
{ _useCache: false,
  _tzInfo: {},
  _day: NaN,
  year: NaN,
  month: NaN,
  date: NaN,
  hours: NaN,
  minutes: NaN,
  seconds: NaN,
  milliseconds: NaN,
  timezone: 'America/New_York',
  _dateProxy: Invalid Date,
  _timeProxy: NaN }
{ _useCache: false,
  _tzInfo: {},
  _day: NaN,
  year: NaN,
  month: NaN,
  date: NaN,
  hours: NaN,
  minutes: NaN,
  seconds: NaN,
  milliseconds: NaN,
  timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
  _dateProxy: Invalid Date,
  _timeProxy: NaN }
```

I need to print like this

```
PDT  --> Sat Jun 17 2017 11:46:54
MDT  --> Sat Jun 17 2017 11:24:54
CDT  --> Sat Jun 17 2017 11:45:54
EDT  --> Sat Jun 17 2017 11:12:54
MST  --> Sat Jun 17 2017 11:33:54
EST  --> Sat Jun 17 2017 11:22:54
IST  --> Sat Jun 17 2017 12:16:54
```

Is it possible to convert unix timestamp to different local times using timezone?

Comment: Im pretty sure you need to convert your timestamp into date string. From docs timezoneJS.Date(dt_str_tz, [tz]). So try to change 123412341234 -> 10/31/2008 or any date you want.

Comment: Your time zone list is a bit strange, btw.  You have PDT for New York, picked Cuba for CDT, etc..  If you were looking for the primary time zones of the USA, the list usually chosen (from East to West) is: `America/New_York`, `America/Chicago`, `America/Denver`, `America/Phoenix`, `America/Los_Angeles`, `America/Anchorage`, `Pacific/Honolulu`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the `timezone-js` package, but kept getting errors in npm.runkit.com,
so I decided to show you an example with the popular [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It also has a sub-module `moment-timezone`:

```
npm install -S moment-timezone
```

And using it is simple!

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

let timestamp = moment(1497678894647);
let NYTime = timestamp.tz('America/New_York').format('ddd MMM D Y HH:mm:ss');
console.log(NYTime);
```

Which logs:

```
"Sat Jun 17 2017 01:54:54"
```

You can see an example on npm.runkit [here](https://runkit.com/58fb0a56d5b2bc0012bdf6ed/5944d19b7f5709001202fbc1).

**Edit:**

So given your console.log statements, you'd pass them variables like

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment.defaultFormat = 'ddd MMM D Y HH:mm:ss';

var PDT = moment('1497680592200').tz('America/New_York').format();
var MDT = moment('1497680592200').tz('America/Chihuahua').format();
var CDT = moment('1497680592200').tz('America/Havana').format();
var EDT = moment('1497680592200').tz('America/Detroit').format();
var MST = moment('1497680592200').tz('America/Creston').format();
var IST = moment('1497680592200').tz('Asia/Kolkata').format();
```

Comment: That's great! :)

Comment: i got incorrect date time when changing my code to                                var zone='Asia/Kolkata';                                                                            var IST = moment('1497680592200').tz(zone).format();   ... why this behavior?.  I also tried with                                                                    var IST = moment('1497680592200').tz("'"+zone+"'").format();                    i got error message.

Comment: @MattJohnson they can be, moment will parse them either way.

Comment: @AbdulManaf What was your error? And you don't have to buffer zone with concatenating empty strings.

Comment: @Kano - If you pass it as a string, you need to also pass `x` as a parameter.  Otherwise you will get an deprecation warning, because you are not guaranteed that the fallback to `Date` object's parser will work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript you can use the below syntax to convert the date and time to different timezone

```
var PDT = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles' });
var MDT = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Chihuahua' });
var CDT = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Havana' });
var EDT = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Detroit' });
var MST = new Date(timestamp).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/Creston' });
```

Hope this will work

Comment: what about IST time

Comment: new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'Asia/Calcutta' })